# Recursive method returning an int not compiling

Tags: java, recursion

I'm learning Java at the moment and have a task where I should create a method that keeps asking the user for input until one of two keywords are entered. It should then, depending on that return an int.

```
public static int getCommand(){
    String command = IOTools.readString("Enter Command!");
    if (command.equals("exit")){
        return 1;
    } else if (command.equals("shift")){
        return 0;
    } else {
        getCommand();
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that eclipse tells me to either change the return type to void or add a return statement after the if block. 
[image]
Is there something wrong with my recursive approach?

Comment: why not just get rid of the last else?

Comment: Line 43: `return getCommand();` instead of just `getCommand();` Although, I would not do a recursive approach on something like this. Your stack usage could continue to grow (if not optimized for tail recursion) as invalid commands are entered. Just use a loop.

Comment: You need to _always_ return a value, even in your else-branch (e.g. `return getCommand();`).

Comment: Are you *required* to implement this recursively?  That practically begs for a stack overflow, which could very easily be resolved by making the method iterative instead of recursive.

Comment: I'm not, but couldn't come up with an compact way of writing it. Started with a while(true){} loop, but wasnt really happy with that. Do you have any better ideas?

Comment: Ok forget that, got it :) Was over engineering like crazy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add a `return` type in last case

```
public static int getCommand(){
    String command = IOTools.readString("Enter Command!");
    if (command.equals("exit")){
        return 1;
    } else if (command.equals("shift")){
        return 0;
    } else {
        return getCommand();
    }
}
```

this function `getCommand();` call is returning an `int` value but not in `else` case so if the control falls inside your `else` case then your recursive functions calls will be executed though there is no assurance that `getCommand();` will return an `int` value due to `else` case so compiler detects that hence the error and according to this case where `return` type is not `void` , java says

> Every execution path in a function must lead to a RETURN statement

Answer (score 6):

You are missing the `return` statement on your recursive call

```
public static int getCommand(){
    String command = IOTools.readString("Enter Command!");
    if (command.equals("exit")){
        return 1;
    } else if (command.equals("shift")){
        return 0;
    } else {
        return getCommand(); // Added return here
    }
}
```

Comment: dude you were so quick , ans in just 11 sec , great

Comment: Thanks a lot :) And damn, crazy fast haha

Comment: @PaulEtscheit  yeah even my page took a refreshing to see this answer :P

Answer (score 1):

Return statement is missing here

```
else {
   getCommand();
}
```

All paths of your methode need to return something.